# Jquery onclick image id to form input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a dynamic form... and it has a input field something like

```
<form class=""
<input name="image_0" .. />
<input name="image_1" .. />
<input name="image_4" .. />
<input name="image_6" .. />
<input name="image_7" .. />
....
</form>
```

and i have a another ul li block which gets images from Facebook albums... when we click on the image its "id" has to fill in empty of anyone of input field and no repeated selection...

Image: [Check this image may be it helps to understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylBfG.png)

EDIT:

```
<form class="fb_upload_id" method="get">
    image_2:<input name="image_2" type="text">
    image_3:<input name="image_3" type="text">
    image_4:<input name="image_4" type="text">
</form>

<ul class="facebook_album_photo_list">
    <li alt="Paradise Vision from http://Stockwallpapers.in" title="Paradise Vision from http://Stockwallpapers.in" id="463526207001195">
        <a style="background: url(https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/427440_463526207001195_392636722_s.jpg) center top no-repeat;" class="overlay_photo" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="add_image_fb('463526207001195');"></a>
    </li>
    <li alt="Anonymous Mask from http://Stockwallpapers.in" title="Anonymous Mask from http://Stockwallpapers.in" id="463151140372035">
        <a style="background: url(https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/10476_463151140372035_468769127_s.jpg) center top no-repeat;" class="overlay_photo" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="add_image_fb('463151140372035');"></a>
    </li>
    <li alt="Mirana Nightshade Priestess of the Moon from http://Stockwallpapers.in" title="Mirana Nightshade Priestess of the Moon from http://Stockwallpapers.in" id="463137303706752">
        <a style="background: url(https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/482085_463137303706752_723444526_s.jpg) center top no-repeat;" class="overlay_photo" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="add_image_fb('463137303706752');"></a>
    </li>
    <li alt="Fluid Flow in Lauterbrunnen from http://Stockwallpapers.in" title="Fluid Flow in Lauterbrunnen from http://Stockwallpapers.in" id="459694870717662">
        <a style="background: url(https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/312978_459694870717662_1068867909_s.jpg) center top no-repeat;" class="overlay_photo" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="add_image_fb('459694870717662');"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Give us more example html.  What you have given us isn't enough.  Some html concerning how the pictures are laid out would help us.

Comment: Do you have an input for each image? What happens if I click 4 different images and you only have 3 inputs? Overwrite one of them?

Comment: i think u need more specific.. please check this site.. [link](http://demo.wstheme.com/fb_test/covergen/2) ... login using ur facebook account and click on upload from facebook button...

Comment: I see, take a look at my answer, and see if it suits you.

Comment: yes u have input for each images...some image have 3 some of them have 5 (different input) ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `onclick` event handler is already bound to `add_image_fb`, just add the following:

```
function add_image_fb(id) {
  $('.fb_upload_id input:text[value=""]').first().val(id);
}
```

**Update:**

```
function add_image_fb(id) {
    var inputs=$(".fb_upload_id input:text[value='']");
    if(!inputs.length) alert('All input fields filled up!');
    else inputs.first().val(id);
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/creC9/1/).

Comment: how to get if users selected all input fields...?

Comment: To see if users filled all input fields, you need to compare the total number of fields against the ones that have been filled, i.e., `$('.fb_upload_id input:text').length == $('.fb_upload_id input:text[value!=""]')`.

Comment: I was just trying to answer but, anyway, you can use [this](http://jsfiddle.net/creC9/1/).